# Swift3: How to get images in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, image, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm a beginner to swift3 and I'm having problems on getting the images out of UICollectionView. I followed this tutorial(https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController) on uploading multiple images from photo library but I do not know how to retrieve the images out from the UICollectionView.

[image: Screenshot of the UICollectionView]

The code from the ViewController

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let asset = self.assets![indexPath.row]
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell?
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    if asset.isVideo {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellVideo", for: indexPath)
        imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    } else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellImage", for: indexPath)
        imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    }

    if let cell = cell, let imageView = imageView {
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let tag = indexPath.row + 1
        cell.tag = tag
        asset.fetchImageWithSize(layout.itemSize.toPixel(), completeBlock: { image, info in
            if cell.tag == tag {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you want actually ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you would do something like this to get the images from the `collectionView`.

```
var imagesArray = [UIImage]()
for i in (0...collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell = collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UIImageView
        let image = imageView.image
        imagesArray.append(image!)
}
```

I would advise you to fetch the images from assets library. Because this line of code `let cell = collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)` effectively does the same thing.

Comment: Oh i see... How can I fetch images from assets library?